# WindowsFilteringPlatformの動かし方がわかりません

Tags: c++

https://github.com/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/trans/WFPSampler
このプログラムを動かしたいのですがビルドのところで以下のようなエラーが出てしまうのですがどうすればよいのでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
エラー 1203    Section [wfpcalloutclassreg] not found. WFPSamplerCalloutDriver 
C:\Users\ユーザー名\Desktop\Windows-driver-samples-master\network\trans\WFPSampler\sys\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.inx   51  

エラー LNK1181 入力ファイル 'api-ms-win-net-isolation-l1-1-0.lib' を開けません。    WFPSamplerService   
C:\Users\ユーザー名\Desktop\Windows-driver-samples-master\network\trans\WFPSampler\svc\LINK  1
```

**環境:**
Windows 10 Pro 64bit
Visual Studo Community 2019 16.10.0

Answer (score 0):

stack overflow 本家の方で同じ質問が見つかりました。

当該のページは以下です。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837612/wfpsampler-compilation-issue-wfpcalloutsclassreg-not-found

要はタイプミスだそうです。
(X)WFPCalloutClassReg
(O)WFPCalloutsClassReg

sなしの行にsを入れるようです。